# Import Statement Inconsistencies

Tags: python, django

Why does the 2nd statement below not work even though it is functionally equivalent to the 1st?

```
from django.shortcuts import render # works
import django.shortcuts.render as render # doesn't work
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't use images to convey important parts of your question. They make the question unsearchable and inaccessible for people with disabilities.

Comment: The two are not functionally equivalent, you can write `from django.shortcuts import render as render`

Comment: @MatsLindh If I add invisible captions to the images that contains the code, would that solve the problem of searchability?

Comment: Yes, but there really is no need. Code is text; add it as text.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  Interesting, I didn't know people actually spent that much effort answering a question such as copy-pasting the code and "investigating" it. In this case, I can see why an image may not be such a good idea. I assumed when they come upon a question they either know the answer off the top of their head or just moved on to the next question.

Comment: @NoName: well perhaps not here no. But often people post 10-20 lines. Yesterday I solved a problem where the person did not wrote `x` but the times character `×`. If you submit this through an image, it is very hard to find that out (and know for sure). Furthermore even if this get answered, how will people *find* your answer when they face the same problem. People with visual impairment will have a hard time reading code on images, and finally such images look "ugly" if the style of the page is different (StackOverflow now has a *dark* color scheme as well, so it does not look very pleasant).

Comment: @NoName: I did not downvote btw (as the name of the site might suggest), it is only a set of reasons why images are actually not a good idea (or at least not *without* a copy of the code). Often such questions get downvoted/closed. Yes that is quite rude, but when asking a question, you should, to some extent also care about future readers.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Okay, I will remember that on my next post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you why: `render` isn't a module.

An example that might make it clearer - lets try to import a function from the `math` module:

```
>>> import math.pow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pow
>>> from math import pow
>>>
```

The `pow` function isn't a module, but the symbol (i.e. the function) can be imported *from* the module (`math`).

`render()` in [django.shortcuts is a function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#render). It's not a module.

Comment: So `from` statements can import both modules and functions in the library, whereas `import` statements can only import modules in the library?

Comment: Correct; `from` and `import` isn't the same semantics; the first imports a symbol (which may be a module itself) defined under a module (given as the argument), while the second imports a module.

Answer (score 2):

Because `render` is a function, while you can only `import` modules.

You can `from a_module import an_object`, but you can only `import a_module as whatever`.

Answer (score 2):

That is because you have to either run `import django` or `from django.(whatever you want) import (your func or var)`. Python does not like it when you call `import (your module).(whatever path)` because then you would be importing a path. Also, `django.shortcuts.render` is not an existing module, you have to import `render` which is a function.

Answer (score 2):

The reason being is `render()` is a function from `django.shortcuts` module.

You can only import the module in python and not function directly.

so you can do:

```
from module import specific_function
```

or simply

```
import module
```

or alias a module only

```
import module as xyz
```

or alias a specific_function from a module

```
from module import specific_function as abc
```